# Any tutorials for using GData API to upload to video to youtube form iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, gdata

Anyone one tell me where can I find tutorials to teach me how to use GData to upload a video to youtube from my iOS app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find a well written example from creators' page of GData for Objective C. 
You just need to download the latest source from his project svn (Just type this code on your terminal application)

```
svn checkout http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ~/Desktop/gdata-objectivec
```

and search inside ~/Desktop/gdata-objectivex/Examples/YoutubeSample. 
In this directory there is a project implementing login with Oauth2, upload of a video and more operations.

This is the basic, I also suggest you to read the general API from youtube here http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html.

Comment: There is no such folder inside. Please suggest a good example of how to upload a video to youtube from iOS app.