# uploling video in youtube in iphone App

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

is there any tutorial for uploling video in youtube using GData API. i want to upload video which are stored in iphone. plzzz give me link if it is

Comment: Check  this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528568/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-from-within-an-ios-application)

Comment: same as this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860923/any-tutorials-for-using-gdata-api-to-upload-to-video-to-youtube-form-ios-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an excellent video tutorial for this [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVMkRUhibsk)